# Child class Changing a protected variable from a Parent class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I know that it is bad design to have a protected variable in a parent class because all child classes can change that value. However, I was trying to test it out but I am doing something wrong here. It's telling me that cannot find symbol `speed = 999999;` in Truck class. I thought the child class has access to the protected variable `speed` in parent class.

```
public class Vehicle {
    protected double speed;
    protected double maxSpeed;

    public Vehicle(double speed, double maxSpeedIn) throws InvalidDataException{
        setSpeed(speed);
        maxSpeed = maxSpeedIn;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double s) throws InvalidDataException {
        if (s < 0.0) {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Negative speed is not valid" );
        }
        if (s > maxSpeed) {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Speed cannot exceed maximum spped:");
        }
        speed = s;
    }


}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    public Truck(double speedin, double maxSpeedin) throws InvalidDataException {
        super(speedin,maxSpeedin);
    }

    speed = 999999;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *speed = 99999;* line isn't valid the way you placed it in the *Truck* class.  Try to put it somewhere else.

You could for example, just for your testing purpose, put it inside *Truck*'s constructor, after the call to *super*.

Note that you'd have had the exact same error if you had chosen another name altogher, like this:

```
public Truck extends Vehicle {

    public Truck(double speedin, double maxSpeedin) throws InvalidDataException {
        super(speedin,maxSpeedin);
    }

    justTesting = 999999;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java you cannot simply write instructions (like `speed = 999999;`) in the middle of a class. Instructions must be written inside a method (function). What actually did you mean? When do you want this instruction to be carried out?

By the way, when `setSpeed` is called by the `Vehicle` constructor `maxSpeed` is not yet initialised, which will cause an error when you try to compare `s` and `maxSpeed`.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access the variable outside of a method body, it needs to be in a constructor or method in the child class in order for you to gain access to it the way that you want.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion protected variables doesn't have to be a bad thing. In some cases it really can be a necessity. But it depends on the design of course :)

In this case I think it makes perfect sense. And you should be able to change the `speed` value in the Truck class. The problem here is (probably) that the line `speed = 999999;` isn't placed inside a method in the class. I might be wrong, but it would seem to me Java compiles it as code unrelated to the class, and thus the speed variable cannot be found. Try putting it in the constructor and see what happens.